# User can delete block and add it again until he got 25 div

Tags: jquery

How can i change this code to do it with limit max 25 times. User can delete block and add it again, always with a max of 25 times

HTML

**holderBlock** - it holds everithing

**repeaterIngredient** - this is the cloned div

```
<div id="holderBlock">

<div class="repeaterIngredient">                         

    <div class="row grid-12-12">
        <label for="extens_ingredientName" title="Tooltip Information">Ingredient name<span class="entity">T4094</span><em class="form-req"><img src="../../Content/Images/ico_transparent.png" alt="required" /></em></label>
        <textarea name="extens_ingredientName" id="extens_ingredientName" class="textArea70"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Remove Ingredient" title="Remove Ingredient" class="formee-button right remove_ingredient">
        <input type="button" value="Add New Ingredient" title="Add New Ingredient" class="formee-button right add_ingredient">
    </div> 

</div>
```

Jquery

This code is for clone the **repeaterIngredient** class and increment the for, name and id of all form elements inside
The user can create another **repeaterIngredient** and delete it, but i need to change this code so than it stops wen it hits 25 divs and to work again if user delete div and add it again

```
var template = $('#holderBlock .repeaterIngredient:first').clone(),

        ingredientsCount = 1;

        var addIngredient = function () {

            ingredientsCount++;

            var repeaterIngredient = template.clone().find(':input').each(function () {

                var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length - 1) + ingredientsCount;

                $(this).prev().attr('for', newId); // update label for (assume prev sib is label)

                this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)

            }).end() // back to .repeaterIngredient

                .attr('id', 'repeaterIngredient' + ingredientsCount) // update repeaterIngredient id

                .appendTo('#holderBlock'); // add to container
        };

        //EXECUTE FUNCTION
        $('input.add_ingredient').live("click", addIngredient); // attach event

        // HIDE FIRST REMOVE BUTTON
        $('#holderBlock input.remove_ingredient:first').hide();

        // DELETE CREATED BLOCK
        $('input.remove_ingredient').live("click", function () {
            //console.log($(this).parent());
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before create you need count visible divs:

```
if ($('.repeaterIngredient:visible').count() > 25)
  return;
```

also you need add class `repeaterIngredient`:

```
...
.attr('id', 'repeaterIngredient' + ingredientsCount)
.addClass('repeaterIngredient')
.appendTo('#holderBlock');
...
```

You can ease optimise script if you removing `.repeaterIngredient` instead of hide:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

and you dont need to count visible items:

```
if ($('.repeaterIngredient').count() > 25)
  return;
```

P.S. I don't test this code. I hope help to you.

Comment: @DanielBatista: you're welcome. If answer is right don't forget to check it.